# How is OAuth2 secure vs man-in-the-middle attacks

Tags: oauth, api

I'm currently researching on securing internal API calls and became interested in request signing since it seems quite secure (using a secret that you won't be sending to anyone to sign your request feels pretty safe).

My problem is that most API Gateway services offer OAuth2 mechanisms. I have serious doubts about its security.

**Can someone explain if it's actually secure to send your credentials to obtain a token and use that in an `Authorization` header?**

I can't help but feel anyone that can successfully obtain the information of the first request will have *all he needs* to impersonate you on future API calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You brush upon an important part of the OAuth2 standard.

Namely, all access is bound to IP and is time-limited. (as in x minutes).
After that you need to request a new token through the authentication mechanism.

Another part of the standard inplace to secure against eavesdropping is that all OAuth2 Acces providers *MUST* implement a TLS or SSL connection. (no HTTP allowed).

But you are correct in that if someone can actually eavesdrop the full connection from the start (as in first authentication with the full oauth  authentication and authorization process) has all the information to connect to the service from your IP.

This is however the same whether you would logon directly to the service.

Comment: Worth mentioning it's still possible to eavesdrop on SSL/TLS connections too, especially in corporate environments that use their own root CA or content proxy.

Comment: @LvB Re: your fourth paragraph; not just "from your IP", but from any IP, since the primary credentials would be exposed.

Comment: @GregSchmit possibly... most times the session is locked to the IP that negotiated the credentials. so at least from your IP, at worst from any IP.